# Problem with conditional logic in Rails: instance method does not return expected value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm developing a Rails app that allows users to post. I want posts to be anonymous if the anon field in the database is set to 1. To implement this functionality, I added a method in my Post model called display_author, which is supposed to return the username if anon is 0 and the string "Anon" if anon is 1.

Models

```
    def display_author
        if anon == 0
            'Anon'
          else
            user.users
          end
    end
```

Views Post

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.display_author %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that even when anon is 1, I still see the username instead of "anon". I've gone through my code several times and tried to debug it, but I can't figure out why it's not working as expected.

The problem is that even when anon is 1, I still see the username instead of "anon". I've gone through my code several times and tried to debug it, but I can't figure out why it's not working as expected.

Comment: As per the problem code should return the username if anon is 0 and the string "Anon" if anon is 1

But as per code `if anon == 0 then 'Anon'`

Comment: It is not resolved if it is 1 or 0, it does not matter

Comment: just print value of `anon` in console and check or use `self.anon`

Comment: I already used the "self" but now the problem is the anon regardless if it is 0 or 1

Comment: please add updated code and print value of `anon` in the top of `display_author`

Comment: What is the datatype of that column in the database? I would expect it to be a boolean for a use-case like this. Did you use a boolean or an integer?

Comment: 'def display_author 
          if self.anon == 0
            user.users
          else
            'Anon'
          end
    end'

Comment: integer @spickermann integer

Comment: @spickermann The problem was the database, I changed to boolean and it works

Comment: What exactly is `anon`? Is it an instance method?

Answer (score -1):

Step one: choose a testing framework.

Seriously, you have a basic issue with your code.  You need to test.

Once you have a testing framework and a basic test that fails, add a debug line before `if anon == 0` and find out what anon actually is (hint, it ain't 0).

Then step into the anon method and see what's going on.